# how to get element from custom list using setonitemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview

I have done a simple task of getting data from database and then inflate it on listview.but i am facing problem when i click on listrow it is not selected and when i click on text which i put down on list from database then it perform selection(setonitemclicklistenr works)....and i also want to pass that particular listrow_text to other activity to edit that text....i have tried one way to perform   clicklistener on view in getview() but its not accepting startActivity(intent) command

and how do i get that text if i use setonitemclicklistener in the activity class...
I am a beginner and facing problem in understanding code which i searched for my problems....

list class where i use custom adapter

```
package com.example.smarttext2;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.AdapterView;
     import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
     import android.widget.ListView;
     import android.widget.Toast;



   public class dialoglist extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        Cursor cursor;
int count;
String[] str;
dialogadapter adapter;
database demo2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialoglist);

    demo2 = new database(getApplicationContext());

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    cursor = demo2.fetch();
    count = cursor.getCount();
    str = new String[count];

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        str[i]=cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    adapter = new dialogadapter(this, str);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapview, View view, int position,
                long pos_id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String pos = view.toString();//this line gives some value like          android.widget.linearlayout473y5834434....
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(dialoglist.this,third.class);
            intent.putExtra("key",pos);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



}
```

}

adapter class

```
      package com.example.smarttext2;



    public class dialogadapter extends BaseAdapter {
           Context context;
           String[] str1;
           LayoutInflater inflater;

  public dialogadapter(Context con,String[] st1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     context = con;
     str1 = st1;
     inflater = ((Activity)con).getLayoutInflater();
} 

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return str1.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglistitem, null);
    final TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(str1[position]);


    return v;
}
```

}

activity where i want to send my data

```
 package com.example.smarttext2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class third extends Activity {
        EditText et1;
        Button btn1;
        database demo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str1 = intent.getStringExtra("key");

    et1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    et1.setText(str1);

    demo = new database(getApplicationContext());

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            demo.add(et1.getText().toString());
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: arg2 is your position, arg1 is your view in your list. That means `String pos = arg1.toString();` should be removed and replace `intent.putExtra("key",pos);` with `intent.putExtra("key",arg2);`. I also recommend renaming your arguments from their default values to something more descriptive.

Comment: @zgc7009 intent.putExtra("key",arg2); will pass the position of item in list.I want to pass item at that particular position....
using String pos = arg0.getItematPosition(arg2).tostring(); is showing error...

Comment: Gotcha, misunderstood. To get the string modify your adapters getItem() method to return the string and in onItemClick to get the string do adapter.getItem(arg2);

Comment: ITs still not working....@zgc7009 its again giving the index of item that is 0,1,or 2.... HOw to modify getItem() of adapter to return string ...Thanku for efforts...

Comment: return str1[arg0]; and change the return type from long to String

Answer (score 0):

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                final long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String string = text.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 3000).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(dialoglist.this,third.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", string);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```